Spring initializing the @Value annotation property from a static field
Having the following code:
public class Constants {
    public static final String X = "-";
}

And in another class
@Value("${some.property:Constants.X")
private String separator;

How can I achieve this?
Constant property is not being loaded

You need to use the T operator with the actual package name where your Constants class is located like below
@Value("#{T(your.package.Constants).X}")
private String separator;

